# While traversing the link list to read data my function prints up to penultimate node only, Suggest a way to print the whole list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, c++14, c++17

I made a linked list in C++. For in which I have a function named: `ListTraverse()`. Which accepts a Node type pointer variable, where Node is my class. Please suggest me a method where it prints up to the last node.
Here is function call:

```
ListTraverse(&head);
```

And here is the function definition:

```
void ListTraverse(Node* node)
{
//Prints upto penultimate node
  while (node->next != NULL)
  {
      cout << "\nNode details:\t"
         << node->read_data();
      node=node->next;
  }
}
```

And here you have the entire code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<typeinfo>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
  private:
  int data;

  public:
  Node *next;
  void push_data(int x)
{
    data = x;
}
int read_data()
{
    return data;
}
};
void ListTraverse(Node *);
int main()
{
 system("CLS");
 //Creating Node type variables
 Node head, second, tail;
int num, choice;
//Getting user input
cout << "Enter a number for head:\t";
cin >> num;
head.push_data(num);
cout << "Enter a number for second:\t";
cin >> num;
second.push_data(num);
cout << "Enter a number for tail:\t";
cin >> num;
tail.push_data(num);
//Assigning pointers to link up
head.next = &second;
second.next = &tail;
tail.next = NULL;
cout << "If you want to read data press 1:\t";
cin >> choice;
switch (choice)
{
case 1:
    ListTraverse(&head);
    break;
default:
    cout << "Invalid choice";
    break;
}
return 0;
}
 //Funtion to print Data
void ListTraverse(Node* node)
{
//Prints upto penultimate node
while (node->next != NULL)
{
    cout << "\nNode details:\t"
         << node->read_data();
    node=node->next;
}
}
```

Comment: Compare to: `while (node) { cout << ...; node = node->next; }`.

Comment: What is wrong with your current function definition? What are your symptoms? Expected and actual results for a fixed, hardcoded example data set?

Comment: The code you posted should work. Perhaps you could edit your question and add what you expect to see, and contrast that with what you're currently seeing.

Comment: Yes, the problem was while traversing the whole list, it would print up to the penultimate node only leaving the last node. The problem was fixed by @olng Sorry for not being precise enough

Comment: You should avoid logic like `while (node->next != NULL)` because you have to make sure `node` is not null before you can test `node->next`. If there is no `node`, there is no `next`, and trying to access that non-existent `next` is [a bad idea](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). If you need to  test `node`, you might as well not bother testing `next` and this puts you at the code recommended by OLNG's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should re-phrase your question. It seems that

my function prints up to penultimate node only

is the problem.

you wanted to print the whole list, not penultimate. And the fix is

```
void ListTraverse(Node* node)
{
//Prints upto the last node
  while (node)
  {
      cout << "\nNode details:\t"
         << node->read_data();
      node=node->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: I rephrased it to make it more clear to understand

Comment: Can you tell me what was `node->next != NULL` was giving this weird result?

Comment: Yes, the last node also has a next. Say the last node from list {1,2,3} is 3, and its next is NULL. So after printing node 2, node is node 3. Now back to the while condition, node 3 -> next ==NULL, and will not get inside the while look and so it can't print the data for node 3.